# jQuery <AREA> appendTo doesn't work in IE7

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-7

I have the following code working fine in IE8 (and IE8 in IE7 compatibility mode) but not generating the right results in IE7

```
var areaId = "eventArea" + index;
var tempArea = $("<AREA id='" + areaId + "' shape='rect' coords='" + value.x + "," + value.y + "," + (parseInt(value.x) + parseInt(value.w)) + "," + (parseInt(value.y) + parseInt(value.h)) + "' >");
tempArea.appendTo($("map[name='wavImageMap']"));
$("#" + areaId).click(function() { alert('test'); });
```

On IE8 these HTML `<AREA>` elements are created and added successfully. But not on IE7. The click event is not happening there.

Comment: Can you do a better job describing what the differences are between IE8 and IE7.  Not entirely clear.

Comment: @Jason, I need to bind events to these AREA elements for clicks and mouseover (to show a tooltip). It works fine in IE8. In IE7 the events are not firing. looks like the element is not being created.

Comment: Since there is no visual indication to the fact the AREA element is created. Does anyone know of an easy way to detect that it is created, and in the right position? So far I'm using the click event to detect that it is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case is not with the `<area>`, but in the way IE7 converts the coordinates to a string. Using `value.x.toString()` instead of `value.x` solves the problem.
The code then will look like this:

```
var tempArea = $("<AREA id='" + areaId + "' shape='rect' >");
tempArea[0].coords = value.x.toString() + "," + value.y.toString() + "," + ((parseInt(value.x) + parseInt(value.w))).toString() + "," + ((parseInt(value.y) + parseInt(value.h))).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the problem, but I had a similar problem and solved it using jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function.  Like so...

```
var areaId = "eventArea" + index;
var tempArea = $("<AREA id='" + areaId + "' shape='rect' coords='" + value.x + "," + value.y + "," + (parseInt(value.x) + parseInt(value.w)) + "," + (parseInt(value.y) + parseInt(value.h)) + "' >");
tempArea.appendTo($("map[name='wavImageMap']"));
$("#" + areaId).live('click', function() { 
    alert('test');
});
```

live() basically ensures that the event is attached to any element that exists now, or in the future (if you create elements on the fly, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems using `.appendTo()` in IE in the past and I can't tell you why; but changing it to `.append()` worked for me.

Comment: Tested with both `.append(element)` and `.append(HTML)` with same results. Works on IE8, fails on IE7 :(